# How does pyspark.mllib.recommendation.ALS make use of user and product info?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

From [pyspark doc](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.recommendation.ALS) we can see:

> classmethod train(ratings, rank, iterations=5, lambda_=0.01,
>   blocks=-1, nonnegative=False, seed=None)[source] Train a matrix
>   factorization model given an RDD of ratings given by users to some
>   products, in the form of (userID, productID, rating) pairs. We
>   approximate the ratings matrix as the product of two lower-rank
>   matrices of a given rank (number of features). To solve for these
>   features, we run a given number of iterations of ALS. This is done
>   using a level of parallelism given by blocks.

So the train method just uses ratings matrix which contains simply userId, productID, and rating. How does this method make use of other information related to userID and productID?

Comment: So how could it be effective?

Comment: This wiki answers my question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collaborative_filtering